# How do I connect a slider to a variable in MFC

Tags: mfc

What's the right way to connect a slider to a member variable in MFC? What I've done so far:

1. Dragged a slider in to my dialog in the resource view and given it an ID
2. Right clicked on the slider and chosen **Add Variable**
3. Set the variable to **Control variable** and the **Category** to **Value** and also set the **Min value** and **Max value** to desired values.

This creates a member variable of type `int` in my dialog class and also adds some stuff to the `DoDataExchange` method.

However, the `DoDataExchange` method is only called once when my dialog is created, what do I have to do to make my member variable update when I drag the slider? Should I have set the **Category** to **Ctrl** instead and manually managed the range, and intercepted the `WM_HSCROLL` messages?

(This is a non modal dialog by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call UpdateData to do the DataExchange passing TRUE to save and validate the data to your variable and FALSE to set the control value based on your variable, ie. passing data into the control. More information about UpdateData:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9fb9hww(v=vs.80).aspx

and for general data exchange mechanism:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwz5tb1x(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: From where should I call UpdateData(TRUE), the WM_HSCROLL message callback?

Comment: If you're intercepting WM_HSCROLL to get the value as soon as the slider changes then I wouldn't bother using a member variable. Just get the value directly from the control. Member variables are only normally used when you have distinct Set/Update points during the app workflow (e.g. Form/Dialog open then apply/close)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you call UpdateData() from within the handler for the control's WM_HSCROLL (or WM_VSCROLL) if it's a vertical slider). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekx9yz55%28v=vs.80%29.aspx .